# UI Service - "...although existing scripts should still function."

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anyone have any indication as to how long they should function?  Google support hasn't been of any help so far in answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

It usually means that you cannot create new applications with the `UIService` class, which is why they remove it from autocomplete. Based on [this blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/12/speeding-up-htmlservice.html), they deprecated the service on December 11, 2014 and removed the option to create new instances on June 30, 2015.

The final line:

> If you have built any UIs using UiApp, they will continue to work.

indicates that if you have existing UI's built before June 30, 2015, that they will continue to work. That being said, it never hurts to double check updates to the official [sunset schedule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset).

Comment: Thanks Brian.  They are still working currently and sunset has passed. I'm trying to figure out how long it'll work.  That's the mystery.

Comment: That's what I mean...it should continue to work. If a specific non-function date is announced, that's when you need to pay attention (take a look at the `DocsList` example).